# How does the either function work and is used appropriately in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, error-handling, either

I am trying to learn Haskell with [Learning Haskell Data Analysis](https://www.packtpub.com/big-data-and-business-intelligence/learning-haskell-data-analysis) at the moment (I read some other things like Learn You a Haskell... before though). There is a listing to parse and modify csv Data that does not work the way the book proposes, ie. it throughs an error. Unfortunately, I am not good enough to be able to correct the listing. I somehow get what does not work but don't know how the correct version would look like. I also did not realy found expressive examples which use the `either` function to see if I can derive the correct version from it

```
module LearningDataAnalysis02 where

import Data.List
import Data.Either
import Text.CSV

-- compute the average of List values
average' :: Fractional a => [a] -> a
average' xs = sum xs / genericLength xs

readColumn :: [String] -> [Double]
readColumn xs = map read xs

getColumnInCSV :: CSV -> String -> Either String Integer
getColumnInCSV csv columnName = case lookupResponse of
    Nothing -> Left "The column does not exist in this csv file."
    Just x  -> Right (fromIntegral x)
  where
    lookupResponse = findIndex (== columnName) (head csv)

applyToColumnInCSV :: ([String] -> b) -> CSV -> String -> Either String b
applyToColumnInCSV func csv column = either
    Left
    Right . func . elements columnIndex
  where
    columnIndex = getColumnInCSV csv column
    nfieldsInFile = length $ head csv
    records = tail $ filter (\record -> nfieldsInFile == length record) csv
    elements ci = map (\record -> genericIndex record ci) records
```

The error message I get when loading it into ghci is:

```
LearningDataAnalysis02.hs:22:38:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Either String b’
                with actual type ‘a0 -> Either a1 b0’
    Relevant bindings include
      func :: [String] -> b (bound at LearningDataAnalysis02.hs:22:20)
      applyToColumnInCSV :: ([String] -> b)
                            -> CSV -> String -> Either String b
        (bound at LearningDataAnalysis02.hs:22:1)
    In the expression: either Left Right . func . elements columnIndex
    In an equation for ‘applyToColumnInCSV’:
        applyToColumnInCSV func csv column
          = either Left Right . func . elements columnIndex
          where
              columnIndex = getColumnInCSV csv column
              nfieldsInFile = length $ head csv
              records
                = tail $ filter (\ record -> nfieldsInFile == length record) csv
              elements ci = map (\ record -> genericIndex record ci) records

LearningDataAnalysis02.hs:24:20:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘a0 -> [String]’
                with actual type ‘[Field]’
    Possible cause: ‘elements’ is applied to too many arguments
    In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘elements columnIndex’
    In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely
      ‘func . elements columnIndex’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Is anyone so kind and can explain to me how I have to modify the listing to make it work and why it does not work the way the book suggest it?

Comment: Well, for one... there is a dot at the end of the last line that's not supposed to be there. Although you'd get a parse rather than a type error if that was in the actual code you were using. The real problem seems to be `Right . func . elements columnIndex` though - `elements ci` is a list, not a function. Also, you need parentheses there otherwise the precedence doesn't work out.

Comment: the dot was a mistake when I copied the code and text into the form. Sorry, I corrected this now since it is not related to the problem.

Comment: Yes, you need parentheses. Function application binds tighter than an operator like `.`, and line breaks are immaterial in the middle of an expression. You wrote `(either Left Right) . func . (elements columnIndex)`.

Comment: thx. in fact changing the line to `either Left (Right . func . elements) columnIndex` does the trick. This is NOT printed in the book which kind of makes me angry. Since you solved the problem do you want to get the credits for answering it, otherwise I answer it today in the evening.

Comment: Honestly... I'd just close it as 'not reproducible' because it's just a typo.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a typo to me. Sounds like the code example in this book was incorrect. That's a question someone else using this book will have again in the future, and it will be nice to have a question with the answer, not a "too localized" closed question.

Comment: I just have to mention that `either Left (Right . f)` is the same as `fmap f`.

Comment: What @ØrjanJohansen said. That's not really a good way to use `either`, because `fmap` is the obvious way to do that.

Comment: I agree on rephrasing the question to relate it to the book but I am not sure what's appropriate. What about: How to make the applyToColumnInCSV exmpl. from 'Learning Haskel Data Analysis work?'